# Why can't `scp` be found even though it is installed?

Tags: scp

I ran the command below.

```
$ scp -i <key> -P <port> <user>@<host>:<path> .
bash: scp: command not found
```

So I checked

```
$ which scp
/usr/bin/scp
```

Then I tried

```
/usr/bin/scp -i <key> -P <port> <user>@<host>:<path> .
bash: scp: command not found
```

I tried

```
$ scp
usage: scp [-346ABCOpqRrsTv] [-c cipher] [-D sftp_server_path] [-F ssh_config]
           [-i identity_file] [-J destination] [-l limit]
           [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] source ... target
$ /usr/bin/scp
usage: scp [-346ABCOpqRrsTv] [-c cipher] [-D sftp_server_path] [-F ssh_config]
           [-i identity_file] [-J destination] [-l limit]
           [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] source ... target
```

So as far as I can tell, the program is

- installed
- on the `$PATH`
- running

I also already tried `sudo apt-get remove openssh-client openssl` and then `sudo apt-get install openssh-client openssl`.

`scp` used to work on my machine just fine... what's going on and/or how can I fix this?

Note, `scp` is installed on the remote server as well.

#### Edit

I ran `scp` with the `-v` flag, as per the comment.

```
$ /usr/bin/scp -v -i <key> -P <port> <user>@<host>:<path> .
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host <host>, user <user>, command scp -v -f <path>
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data <path>
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <host> [<address>] port <port>.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file <path> type 0
debug1: identity file <path> type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u4
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to <host>:<port> as '<user>'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen <path>/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:dBz2B5K8e3bkRhl7S995urLdbvHm34eYlwCUwFyVWNs
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen <path>/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '[<host>]:<port>' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in <path>/.ssh/known_hosts:54
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: <path> RSA SHA256:8c7N6ZX/gpWvY2qQPG4dkTy3LDY51UWaQ2NoaMLhXwE explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: <path> RSA SHA256:8c7N6ZX/gpWvY2qQPG4dkTy3LDY51UWaQ2NoaMLhXwE explicit
debug1: Server accepts key: <path> RSA SHA256:8c7N6ZX/gpWvY2qQPG4dkTy3LDY51UWaQ2NoaMLhXwE explicit
Authenticated to <host> ([<address>]:<port>) using "publickey".
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching <path>/.ssh/known_hosts for [<host>]:<port> / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching <path>/.ssh/known_hosts2 for [<host>]:<port> / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file <path>/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: host key found matching a different name/address, skipping UserKnownHostsFile update
debug1: Remote: <path>/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: <path>/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: channel 0: setting env LANG = "C.UTF-8"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_CTYPE = "en_US.UTF-8"
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -f <path>
bash: scp: command not found
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3024, received 2840 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 28190.5, received 26475.2
debug1: Exit status 127
```

So it says `debug1: Sending command: scp -v -f <path>` right before it fails, so perhaps that means the remote machine has something messed up...

#### Edit 2

I tried accessing my file by just `cat`-ing over ssh.

```
$ ssh -i <key> -p <port> <user>@<host> "cat <file>"
bash: cat: command not found
```

Curious.

```
$ ssh -i <key> -p <port> <user>@<host> "pwd"
/home/<user>
$ ssh -i <key> -p <port> <user>@<host> "echo foo"
foo
$ ssh -i <key> -p <port> <user>@<host> "ls"
bash: ls: command not found
$ ssh -i <key> -p <port> <user>@<host> "whoami"
bash: ls: command not found
$ ssh -i <key> -p <port> <user>@<host> "cd"
$
```

As you can see, some basic commands are not recognized.

#### Edit 3

I ran `echo $PATH` on the remote machine and I got

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

However, I ran `ssh -i <key> -p <port> <user>@<host> "echo \$PATH"` on my local machine, and I got

```
${PATH}:/usr/local/ssl/bin
```

So I think this could be the cause. I have a file on the remote server `/etc/environment` with the following contents:

```
PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/ssl/bin"
```

This could be the culprit.

Comment: If you can invoke to get help, it's probably working. Try and enable verbose logging in `scp` and see what it prints.

Comment: ...`cat` seems to be missing (or not in PATH) on the remote system?

Answer (score 0):

This problem came up when I followed [this guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-openssl-from-source-on-linux/) on building `openssl` from source. I tried to add it to my path, but I did it wrong.

Putting `PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/ssl/bin"` in `/etc/environment` doesn't work. If anyone can explain this in another answer, I will accept that answer. For now I just removed the contents of the file and everything works now.